# Finding largest n factors that equal or almost equal a given number

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I am not a mathematician at all, so don't hesitate to point out if my question is impetuous, vague, or in the wrong forum.

I have two given integers $n$ and $k$. Now, I want to find the largest $k$ integers that equal $n$ *or almost* $n$.

So for example $n = 19$ and $k = 3$ would lead to result $= 6, 3, 1$, result $= 18, 1, 1$ or result $= 3, 3, 2$ because $19$ does not have 3 factors and 18 is the largest number that is smaller than 19 and can be split up in three factors.

Furthermore, I prefer the solution $3, 3, 2$ over $6, 3, 1$ over $18, 1, 1$ as I am looking for the solution with the largest smallest factor (and $(3, 2) > (3, 1) > (1, 1)$).

How can I solve this problem efficiently even for very large numbers?

Comment: Please format your equations with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "How can I solve the problem for large $n,k$" ?  Not very easily.  If prime factorizations are allowed, and if $$n = \prod_{i=1}^r (p_i)^{a_i}$$ then $n$ can be expressed as the product of at most $M = \prod_{i = 1}^r (a_i)$ factors $> 1$.  Assuming that $k \leq M$, then the decision of how to combine the $M$ factors into $k$ factors so as to maximize the minimum of the resultant $k$ factors can be **very complicated** in general.